# Error uploading Feed document with amazon-sp-api: Invalid initialization vector

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cryptojs, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm trying to upload a Feed document to Amazon using the createFeedDocument operation of the Selling Partner API. After the API call, I received a response object containing the feedDocumentId, url, and encryptionDetails, which includes the standard, initializationVector, and key. However, when I try to upload the Feed document using the returned URL, I get an error saying "Invalid initialization vector".

I am using version 0.7.10.

This is the response I get from the callAPI function:
`{ feedDocumentId: '3d4e42b5-1d6e-44e8-a89c-XXXXXXX', url: 'https://d34o8swodXXX.cloudfront.net/Feed_101__POST_PRODUCT_DATA_%2BKEY%3DFeed_101%2BMode%3DCBC%2BINITVEC%3D8f+6c+cc+56+0d+50+a2+d0+31+ec+80+be+f2+6a+1d+0a', encryptionDetails: { standard: 'AES', initializationVector: '8f 6c cc 56 0d 50 a2 d0 31 ec 80 be f2 6a 1d 0a', key: 'key' } }`

The issue I'm facing is with the createCipheriv function call within the SellingPartner.js file of the amazon-sp-api package. Specifically, the error is occurring when the code tries to create a cipher using the initialization vector returned by the Selling Partner API's createFeedDocument operation. The error message reads "TypeError: Invalid initialization vector". I am unable to check or modify the initialization vector as it is returned by the Selling Partner API. The goal of my code is to upload a feed to list a new product to the Amazon catalog, which does not yet exist. The feed object itself should not be related to the issue.

Can someone help me resolve this error? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the older version of the Feeds API. See the [documentation](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feeds-api-v2021-06-30-use-case-guide) for the lastest version which does not include encryption details. The URL returned from the createFeedDocument operation is explained as follows:

> **Amazon S3 presigned URL**: A URL for an S3 bucket from which you can download an object without AWS security credentials or permissions. In some cases the object may be compressed, in which case compressionAlgorithm is returned in addition to the URL. The URL expires after 5 minutes.